# Can I run package.skeleton without parsing functions into separate files?

Tags: r, package

Is it possible to run `package.skeleton('pkgname')` and have all of the `.R` files end up in a single file or set of files rather than one file per function?

A developer I am working with asked me why I had each function in a separate file and my only rationale was 'that is the default behavior`.

Comment: I like having things in separate files.

Comment: @roman Most of my functions have helper functions and i find it easier to keep track if at least related functions are together in a single file.

Comment: Agreed, it would be a waste to have files for each helper function. My current work flow permits me file-per-function with helper functions defined inside those functions (they're usually not applicable elsewhere).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you specify a file containing several functions in the `code_files` argument to `package.skeleton`, that should just be copied to the `R` directory in the package.

So, yes.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. I saw `code_files` but did not realize it had this effect on output.

Comment: sorry I missed that the information was hiding in the details of `?package.skeleton`:  _The package sources are placed in subdirectory ‘name’ of ‘path’. If ‘code_files’ is supplied, these files are copied; otherwise, objects will be dumped into individual source files.  The file names in ‘code_files’ should have suffix ‘".R"’ and be in the current working directory._

Answer (score 1):

Don't use package.skeleton. Create the files yourself and use roxygen to create the documentation.  It's a much easier workflow in the long run.

Comment: thanks for the advice. I think the roxygen guide said to do package.skeleton first and then roxygenize. But this has not had the desired effect so I will try using roxygenize first.